# I can not access all child in listview (eclipse)

Tags: android, listview

Using `Log.i("Number Children", Integer.toString(lista.getChildCount()));` I get 2, but in fact I have 4 children. This complicates my life because I have to edit two graphs in real time and I don't have access to all children.

This is my code for create List:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //interface
        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_monitoramento, container,false);       

        //lista
        lista = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewmonitoramento);                    
        String[] de = {"nome", "potencia", "custo"}; 
        int[] para = { R.id.nome_corrente, R.id.consumo_potencia, R.id.consumo_custo};              

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), listarCorrentes(), R.layout.modelo_lista_correntes, de, para);

        //adaptador de string para reles                
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "adfngfnfbdvs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //here I create my graphs
                gerarGraficos(lista);

            }
        });



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_monitoramento, null); 
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //Remove the listener before proceeding
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                /////////HERE, return a wrong number of children///////////////             
                Log.i("Number Children", Integer.toString(lista.getChildCount()));
                gerarGraficos(lista);

            }
        }); 

        return(view);

    }
```

This is my xml interface item listView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" 
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"> 
            <TextView 
               android:id="@+id/nome_corrente"
               android:text="Sendor Corrente 1" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>          
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/consumo_potencia"
                android:text="Potencia consumida: " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/consumo_custo"
                android:text="Valor estimado: R$ " 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dip"
                android:id="@+id/graph_diario" />
            <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dip"
                android:id="@+id/graph_mensal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

interface listView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:background="#ffffff" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="27/05/2016" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"  
        />  
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewmonitoramento"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the rest of my class, where build the itens on my adapter:

```
    public class Monitoramento extends Fragment {


    ListView lista;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> correntes;



    private List<Map<String, Object>> listarCorrentes() { 
        correntes = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

        Map<String, Object> item;
        item = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

        item.put("nome", "sensor de corrente 0"); 
        item.put("potencia","Potencia consumida hoje: 123 W"); 
        item.put("custo","Valor estimado: R$ 90,00");       
        correntes.add(item);

        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("nome", "sensor de corrente 22"); 
        item.put("potencia","Potencia consumida hoje: 162 W"); 
        item.put("custo","Valor estimado: R$ 122,00");      
        correntes.add(item);

        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("nome", "sensor de corrente 1"); 
        item.put("potencia","Potencia consumida hoje: 100 W"); 
        item.put("custo","Valor estimado: R$ 72,00");       
        correntes.add(item);

        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("nome", "sensor de corrente 2"); 
        item.put("potencia","Potencia consumida hoje: 16 W"); 
        item.put("custo","Valor estimado: R$ 12,00");       
        correntes.add(item);


        return correntes;
    }
////method onCreateView here///////
    }
```

Comment: Children in a ListView? I guess you are talking about an ExpandableListView.

Comment: in method getChildAt(i), sorry I am new in android

Answer (score 0):

You doing wrong things, when trying to get *items* (not *childrens*) through list.getChildCount !
ListView has an adapter, which manage/fill data and set this data to a current item at current adapter position. This proccess not so simple as I discribe, in real life. So, to get items count you should use:

```
yourLstView.getAdapter().getCount()
```

I think, You should visit [Developers Android](https://developer.android.com) and read more.

For cases, when you want modify your data, like you said, to change some values in textView and in GraphView, you should use adapter. Manage data stuff and set it into views - excactly, what adapter doing. 
So, you have some collection of **data, that U wanna display in text/graphView, whatever**. Create custom adapter. Pass this data to adapter, and in **getView** method set this data to needed fields.
Here is example for begginers [how to implement adapter with *ViewHolder* pattern](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/19/android-listview-with-viewholder-tutorial/). This is **Right way, to solve your problem, be sure**

If U get confuse, try to *google* the problem.

And please, wote for my answer, if my post was hepful for you.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I really have problems with desenvovimento on Android. Thanks :)
but anticipating, how do I get my graph_diario item within an item?

Comment: If you describe in details, what you want to do with your items, and what for you want to get _graph_dario_, I'll help you, might be...

Comment: @Roni Rodrigues, I edited my last answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I want a loop that passes through all the items on my list modifying the TextView and graph they have
my code up here is this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < lista.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {             
            GraphView graph1 = new GraphView(lista.getContext()); 
            graph1=(GraphView)lista.findViewById(R.id.graph_diario);
            LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
                    new DataPoint(0, -1),
                    new DataPoint(1, 5),
                    new DataPoint(2, 3),
                    new DataPoint(3, 2),
                    new DataPoint(4, 10)
            });
        }
```